# Android Broadcast Security: Custom Permission AND Specific Receiver Class?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-security

I'm reading up on Android Security when sending broadcasts, and came across these very helpful notes from a talk: https://defcon.org/images/defcon-19/dc-19-presentations/O%27Neil-Chin/DEFCON-19-O%27Neil-Chin-Google-Android.pdf

In the part about unauthorized intent receipt, two possible measures are suggested:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("some.pkg.name", "some.pkg.name.TestDestination");
```

OR

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("my.own.action");
sendBroadcast(i, "my.own.permission");
```

I don't see how those two are mutually exclusive. Is there a reason not to do both if I can, for extra security? In my particular case, since I know the target app/package/class, the first is a given, but I'm wondering if anything should keep me from implementing the second one as well.